# mkdir(): Permission denied [CORE/Cake/Utility/Folder.php, line 546]

Tags: cakephp

I'm uploading user's image in cakephp & using this code.

```
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');

$dir = new Folder ('Upload' . DS . 'Images', true, '0755' );
```

when i'm debugging it is string to find `Folder.php` in application folder, but it exists in lib folder

Edited:

Comment: could you please format code?

Comment: I'm creating a normal controller,model & views

Comment: You find under lib, may be because process working directory is under `lib` folder.